# Timeout on CQL COUNT() restricted by partition key

Tags: cassandra

I have a table in cassandra DB that is populated. It provably has around 10000 records. When I try to execute select count(*), my query times out. Surprisingly, it times out even when i restrict the query with the partition key. The table has a column that is filled with a lot of text. I can't understand how that would be a problem, but i thought, i'd mention it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Doing a `COUNT()` of the rows in a partition shouldn't timeout unless it contains thousands and thousands of rows. More importantly, the query is most likely timing out when the partition contains thousands of tombstones.

You haven't provided a lot of information in your question and ideally you should have included:

- the table schema
- a sample query

In any case if you are storing queue-like datasets and deleting rows after they've been processed (because it's a queue) then you are generating lots of tombstones within the partition. Once you've reached the maximum `tombstone_failure_threshold` (default is 100K tombstones) then Cassandra will stop reading any more rows.

Unfortunately, it's hard to say what's happening in your case without the necessary details. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

A `SELECT COUNT(*)` needs to scan the entire database and can potentially take an extremely long time - much longer than the typical timeout. Ideally, such a query would be *paged* - periodically returning empty pages until the final page contains the count - to avoid timing out. But currently in Cassandra - and also in Scylla - this isn't done.

As Erick noted in his reply, everything becomes worse if you also have a lot of tombstones: You said you only have 10,000 rows, but it's easy to imagine a use case where the data changes frequently, and you actually have for each row 100 deleted rows - so Cassandra needs to scan through 1 million rows (most of them already dead), not 10,000.

Another issue to consider is that when your cluster is very large, scanning usually contact nodes sequentially, and each node many times (depending on the number of vnodes), so the scan time on a very large cluster will be large even if there are just a few actual rows in the database. By the way, unlike a regular scan, an aggregation like COUNT(*) can actually be done internally *in parallel*. Scylla recently implemented this and it speeds up counts (and other aggregation), but if I understand correctly, this feature is not in Cassandra.

Finally, you said that "Surprisingly, it times out even when i restrict the query with the partition key.". The question is **how** you restricted the query with a partition key. If you restricted the partition key itself to a range, it will still be slow because Cassandra still needs to scan all the partitions and compare their keys to the range. What you should have done is to restrict the **token** of the partition key, e.g., something like

```
where token(p) >= -9223372036854775808 and token(p) < ....
```